# Some error occurred concerning record in erlang when compile

Tags: erlang

I'm new to erlang, and here's my code:

```
-module(main).
-author("jasonzhu").

%% API
-export([new/2]).

-record(person, {name, age}).



new(Name, Age) ->
  #person(name=Name, age=Age).
```

When compiling in prompt via `erl main.erl`, the following error occurred:

```
$ erlc main.erl 
main.erl:20: syntax error before: '('
main.erl:13: function new/2 undefined
main.erl:15: Warning: record person is unused
```

Could anyone help me out? I didn't see any explicit culprit against my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the last line it should be braces, not parentheses:

```
new(Name, Age) -> 
    #person{name=Name, age=Age}.
```

See the documentation on [records](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html) for more information (and [examples](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/records.html))